# What constitutes an FAQ question?

Tags: discussion, questions

In a [questions page](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions) - there are categories like [newest](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), [votes](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) etc.

There is also, a tab called [FAQ](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq).

What exactly is this? What is the criteria that defines a question to be called an FAQ?

Just Curious.

Comment: nobody really knows... there's some algorithm that takes into account the number of votes, number of times it's viewed, number of answers, etc. and produces a "faq score", according to which it is rated. I usually ignore that tab.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one that finds it mysterious.

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently a list of questions that get linked to very often (the tooltip says this).

Also see [Grace Note's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95788/160166) to the same question on MSO.